# How to make flex try the second longest matching regular expression?

Tags: regex, token, bison, flex-lexer

This question might sound a little confusing.  I'm using Flex to pass tokens to Bison.

The behavior I want is that Flex matches the longest regular expression and passes that token (it DOES work like this), but if that token doesn't work with the grammar, it then matches the second longest regular expression and passes that token.

I'm struggling to think of a way to create this behavior.  How could I make this happen?

To clarify, for example, say I have two rules:

```
"//"    return TOKEN_1;
"///"   return TOKEN_2;
```

Given the string `"///"`, I'd like it to first pass `TOKEN_2` (it does).
If `TOKEN_2` doesn't fit with the grammar as specified in Bison, it then passes `TOKEN_1` (which is also valid).

How can I create this behavior?

Comment: I'm working with a large file and not using a system with a terminal, so it's hard for me to check things using a simple example.  This isn't the default behavior is it?

Comment: Do you want this for a specific set of rules, or for all rules in general? If the latter, I'd be surprised if you accomplished this using flex.

If it's a specific set of rules, you could and should refactor the rules.

Comment: This token situation is only for two different tokens. Basically, it's I try to treat a comment as a specific type of comment, but if that causes a problem then just treat it as a regular comment.  It would be very tough to refactor my rules in this way, and if I was able to get this token passing method to work I think this would be far simpler.

Answer (score 4):

In `flex`, you can have a rule that tries to do something but fails and tries the second-best rule by using the `REJECT` macro:

> REJECT  directs  the  scanner  to proceed on to the
>             "second best" rule which matched the  input  (or  a
>             prefix  of  the  input).   The  rule  is  chosen as
>             described above in "How the Input is Matched",  and
>             yytext  and  yyleng  set  up appropriately.  It may
>             either be one which matched as  much  text  as  the
>             originally  chosen  rule but came later in the flex
>             input file, or one which matched  less  text.

(source: [The Flex Manual Page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html)).

So to answer your question about getting the second-longest expression, you might be able to do this using `REJECT` (though you have to be careful, because it could just pick something of the same length with equal priority).

Note that `flex` will run slower with `REJECT` being used because it needs to maintain extra logic to "fall back" to worse matches at any point.  I'd suggest only using this if there's no other way to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks...this is helpful and seems to be on the right track.  However, how would REJECT know that the token triggered an error in the rule in Bison?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you cant do that. I'm actually unsure how much flex talks to bison. I do know there is a mode for REPL parsing and i do know there is another mode that parses it all.

You'll have to inline the rule. For example instead of // and / you write a rule which accepts /// then another that assumes /// means // /. But that gets messy and i only did that in a specific case in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would just have the lexer scan two tokens `//` and `/` and then have the parser deal with cases when they are supposed to be regarded as one token, or separate. I.e. a grammar rule that begins with `///` can actually be refactored into one which starts with `//` and `/`. In other words, do not have a `TOKEN_2` at all. In same cases this sort of thing can be tricky though, because the LARL(1) parser has only one token of lookahead. It has to make a shift or reduce decision based on seeing the `//` only, without regard for the `/` which follows.

I had an idea for solving this with a hacky approach involving a lexical tie in, but it proved unworkable.

The main flaw with the idea is that there isn't any easy way to do error recovery in yacc which is hidden from the user. If a syntax error is triggered, that is visible. The `yyerror` function could contain a hack to try to hide this, but it lacks the context information.

In other words, you can't really use Yacc error actions to trigger a backtracking search for another parse.

Answer (score 1):

This is tough for bison/yacc to deal with, as it doesn't do backtracking.  Even if you use a backtracking parser generator like [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/), it doesn't really help unless it also backtracks through the lexer (which would likely require a parser generator with integrated lexer.)

My suggestion would be to have the lexer recognize a slash immediately followed by a slash specially and return a different token:

```
\//\/       return SLASH;
\/          return '/';   /* not needed if you have the catch-all rule: */
.           return *yytext;
```

Now you need to 'assemble' multi-slash 'tokens' as non-terminals in the grammer.

```
single_slash:  SLASH | '/' ;
double_slash:  SLASH SLASH | SLASH '/' ;
triple_slash:  SLASH SLASH SLASH | SLASH SLASH '/' ;
```

However, you'll now likely find you have conflicts in the grammar due to the 1-token lookahead not being enough.  You may be able to resolve those by using [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) or bison's `%glr-parser` option.